# Trace of density matrix

Tags: matrix, physics

Hi friends of Mathematica, i´m a physics student and try to calculate `Tr[rho^4]` for a general two qubit system analytically. Since this is a very long calculation, the probability of making mistakes is almost 1. Therefore i wanted to double check my calculation with the help of Mathematica, but unfortunately it gives me no helpful result. Here is my code:

```
Id = IdentityMatrix[2];
sig[0] = SparseArray[PauliMatrix[0]];
sig[1] = SparseArray[PauliMatrix[1]];
sig[2] = SparseArray[PauliMatrix[2]];
sig[3] = SparseArray[PauliMatrix[3]];
sigv = Table[PauliMatrix[i], {i, 1, 3}];

v1 = {vx, vy, vz};
w1 = {wx, wy, wz};
cM = {{c11, c12, c13}, {c21, c22, c23}, {c31, c32, c33}};


rho = 1/4[
    Id\[CircleTimes]Id + Id\[CircleTimes]v1.sigv + 
     w1.sigv\[CircleTimes]Id + 
     Sum[cM[[i]][[j]].(sig[i]\[CircleTimes]sig[j]), {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 
       3}]];

Tr[rho.rho.rho.rho]
```

I want my result to depend only on the matrix `cM` and the vectors `v1` and `w1`. But it yields some sparse array notifications. It seems as if the calculation is to complicated for Mathematica, although i doubt this highly, since it is my task to do it with pen and paper :) Has someone any suggestions how to obtain a useful result?

Comment: Oh its a typo, but only here in the forum. In my original code its a dot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you want this?

```
rho = 1/4 (KroneckerProduct[Id, Id] + KroneckerProduct[Id, v1.sigv] + 
     KroneckerProduct[w1.sigv, Id] + 
     Sum[cM[[i]][[j]] KroneckerProduct[sig[i], sig[j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j,
        1, 3}]);
Tr[rho.rho.rho.rho] // Simplify
```

Most importantly, you must not use `[ ]`  to group mathematical expression, use `( )` instead.

Comment: Thanks,a lot, this seems to work :D

Comment: Nice. Here's how I'd do the sum: `Total[Normal[Outer[KroneckerProduct, Array[sig, 3], Array[sig, 3], 1] cM], 2]`. Additionally, `Tr[MatrixPower[rho, 4]]` is much more compact.